# Change Oracle 12c database characterset to WE8MSWIN1252 from AL32UTF8 without recreating the DB

Tags: oracle, unicode, oracle12c

The title says it all. Could someone please provide an easy way of changing the DB characterset to WE8MSWIN1252 from AL32UTF8.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: One of the application is giving out errors when used on unicode DB. The devs are saying that the app was designed to run with the default characterset.

Comment: Nowadays `AL32UTF8` is the default characterset for an Oracle database! If your client app does not like Unicode characters, then set the client characterset to `WE8MSWIN1252` using the `NLS_LANG` value. Then you are done.

Answer (score 1):

in this case "the easy way" does not exist as this is a very major change for a database. In this case this is more difficult as you are converting from a "superset" of your target character set.

You can follow this guidelines:

[Character Set Migration using CSSCAN and CSALTER](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/character-set-migration)

[Database Migration Assistant for Unicode (DMU) in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/database-migration-assistant-for-unicode-dmu-12cr1)

You can't use DMU to migrate from AL32UTF8.

csscan and cssalter are deprecated in Oracle 12c but I think that they are still working.

**In 12c and higher the only supported option is to use expdp/impdp into a new database to migrate from AL32UTF8 to other charactersets**, as from metalink note:

> Changing the NLS_CHARACTERSET From AL32UTF8 / UTF8 (Unicode) to another NLS_CHARACTERSET in 8i, 9i , 10g and 11g (Doc ID 1283764.1)

Comment: CSSCAN and CSALTER are not available for 12c. Also DMU cannot be used to convert from AL32UTF8 to other charactersets.